# Document type does not allow element "ul" here

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using XHTML 1.0 Strict Document type.
I have at the end of my page some JavaScript:

```
$.each(x, function(k, v){
    txt += '<li>';
    txt += '<strong>' + v.description     + '</strong>: $' + v.postage;
    txt += '</li>';
```

When I validate my document on the W3.org, it gives me the following error:

> ```
> txt += '<ul><li>';
> ✉
> ```
>
> The element named above was found in a context where it is not allowed. This could mean that you have incorrectly nested elements --
>   such as a "style" element in the "body" section instead of inside
>   "head" -- or two elements that overlap (which is not allowed).
>
> One common cause for this error is the use of XHTML syntax in HTML documents. Due to HTML's rules of implicitly closed elements, this
>   error can create cascading effects. For instance, using XHTML's
>   "self-closing" tags for "meta" and "link" in the "head" section of a
>   HTML document may cause the parser to infer the end of the "head"
>   section and the beginning of the "body" section (where "link" and
>   "meta" are not allowed; hence the reported error).

I am a very beginner in JavaScript, it would be very nice if someone can help me to fix this validation error on my page.

Comment: You just about answered yourself. W3C is complaining you have JavaScript code that's not in your <head> section of your document. Most people place their script in a seperate file, and then include it in the header section

Comment: Is your (inline) script enclosed in [CDATA-Tags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA)?

Comment: @Lee Scott: Since when were `<script>` tags not allowed outside `<head>`?

Comment: I really have no idea.. But that's what the error is saying, it might have something to do with the HTML type he declared

Comment: @LeeScott - that's _not_ what the error is saying, it only has suggestions about common causes of the problem and doesn't mention script blocks at all (it _does_ say that _style_ elements should go in the head, so maybe you've conflated the two?). See the answers for the real problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you're in an inline script element that's still parsed by the XML parser (in theory). Your tags inside the JavaScript strings might be counted as elements.

One solution (the best solution, which you should be doing already) is to simply move your JavaScript into an external file and link to it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="my/script.js"> </script>
```

The other ones involve escaping or using `<![CDATA[` blocks, and are generally unpleasant.

Comment: Minitech, Should i copy this script from <script>to the end of </script> and save it in a file that has JS extension and link it as you suggested above?

Answer (score 0):

The validator is incorrectly picking up the HTML tags that are inside your script block. Move your script to an external file to get rid of this issue.

> The validator complains about something in my JavaScript!
>
> Most probably, you should read the script section of WDG's excellent
>   Common HTML Validation Problems document.

See: http://validator.w3.org/docs/help.html#faq-javascript

Comment: Hello, I have a link to the script it is already linked inside the <head> tag. But i understand that my script needs some <script></script> inside of my page as well to make my script function. should i just move the <script></script> code to the <head> section?

Comment: Your post says it's at the end of your page, not an external file.

Comment: Use something like: <script src="myfile.js"></script> and put your code in the external file.

Comment: Thank you so much guys, your answers were so helpful, problem is resolved now.